# Why does dask head() check only first partition by default?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

dask version 1.1.4

I was caught off-guard by the fact that dask.dataframe.head() does not behave similarly to pandas.

Filtered dask.dataframe seems to keep rows in original partitions. If all rows of a partition are filtered out then partition is left empty but still kept in resulting dask.dataframe. If len(first partition) < n then head(n) doesn't look beyond and misses rows.

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

dd = dask.datasets.timeseries()

# Original partitions lengths
print(dd.map_partitions(len).compute())

# Since len(first partition) > 5, head() works fine
print(dd.head())

# Now we filter data
dd_filter = dd[dd['id'] <= 870]

# Observe the empty partitions and those with len < 5
print(dd_filter.map_partitions(len).compute())

# Note the difference between the following two outputs:
print(dd_filter.head())
print(dd_filter.compute().head())
```

The two outputs are not identical.

The UserWarning when head(n) returns less than n rows does suggest to increase npartitions which solves the problem:

```
.../dask/dataframe/core.py:4494: UserWarning: Insufficient elements for `head`. 5 elements requested, only 0 elements available. Try passing larger `npartitions` to `head`.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(n, len(r)))
```

But I would rather not have to keep this in mind every time I use dask. Also, it seems performance suffers significantly if npartitions is set to -1 always even if most partitions are empty.

My question is what is the reasoning behind this particular design? Is it possible to match pandas behaviour by simply traversing through the partitions until n rows are collected or partitions are exhausted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is what is the reasoning behind this particular design? Is it possible to match pandas behaviour by simply traversing through the partitions until n rows are collected or partitions are exhausted?

In some cases, yes, what you suggest would be very feasible, but not in all.  For example, consider the case where your dataframe is the result of a sorting operation.  We can compute the first partition, realize that it isn't enough, but unfortunately at this point we've tossed out all of the previous data.

Should we recompute the full sorted dataset?  That's expensive

Should we compute a few partitions just in case?  That may or may not fit in memory.

At the end of the day the only thing we can do is warn and tell the user what's happening so that they can make a well informed decision on their own.